# i want to see create table definition again after creating table in sql plus in oracle

Tags: oracle

I just created a table in Oracle sqlplus.

```
sql>create table test1
(Name varchar(15), Mobile _num number(15)) ;
```

so I want a solution where  I can see again this definition.
just typing a command or other solution.

output should be in same way

```
create table test1
(Name varchar(15), Mobile _num number(15)) ;
```

Comment: You can try this one: desc test1;

Comment: Yes just run: `desc test1;` to get the table description.

Comment: Definitely a duplicated question, and definitely @EduardUta has right. The fastest way is `desc test1` where `desc` stands for `describe`.

Comment: I don't think that this is what you are talking about; it is not the `DESC`(ribe) command; the OP wants to see the whole `CREATE TABLE` statement - have a look at the question. If that's so, `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'TEST1', 'USER_WHO_OWNS_IT') from dual;` would be a better answer. Though, the question has been closed. Too bad. **EDIT** Ah, yes - I see it now, there's a link which leads to the same `GET_DDL`. OK then.

Comment: `set echo on` - it should repeat the last statement. you create a table - it outputs the statement after you execute it.